# Preg_match_all and javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, regex, arrays, preg-match-all

I want to extract number "28" from javascript array:

`array.content(2,'28','0');`

so i wrote something like this using the regex:

`(preg_match_all("/array.content(2,\'(.*?)\');/", $result, $con)`

it does not work, please help ;)

Comment: first of all, the parameter order of preg_match_all is wrong, if the name of variables reflect the value of it. switch `$result` and `$con`

Comment: Are you trying to modify the string or just retrieve the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
        "/array\.content\(2\,\'?([0-9]+)\'?\,[^\)]*\)\;/ui"
```

And swiitch `$result` variable with `$con` in the parameters of `preg_match_all`
Test here: http://regexr.com?34e0q

If the first parameter is not always 2 (but a numeric variable) you could use this:

```
        "/array\.content\(\'?[0-9]+\'?,\'?([0-9]+)\'?\,[^\)]*\)\;/ui"
```

Test: http://regexr.com?34e16

See your results:

```
var_dump($result);  //$result[1] contains what you need ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Javascript**

If you are trying to remove the element, take a look at Javascript's [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

If you are trying to find the element, just use [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

In **PHP**

```
preg_match_all(#\((.*)(,|\))#, "array.content(2,'28','0');", $matches);
```

You may want to clarify your question and take a look at php's [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) documentation.